# Use for loop to select different columns by names in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Now I have a table like this.

```
Table name: itemlist

Item year value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 ... value99
--------------------------------------
foo1  12    32    48
foo2  13    32    50
foo3  14    32    50
foo4  15    33    48
foo5  16    33    48
foo6  17    33    48
foo7  13    38    42
foo8  14    34    44
foo9  15    36    46
foo10 16    37    48
```

Here's the task, I want to find out **for each value(such as value1, value2, etc.), how many items are above 35, how many are below 35.**

Is there a way to *loop* the process so I don't have to select everything from each value column.

This is an example of select one of the column.

```
SELECT count(value1) as v1_number
FROM itemlist
WHERE v1_number > 35
UNION
SELECT v1_number
FROM itemlist
WHERE v1_number <35;
```

This works but I have to type this in 99 times.

So my solution would be a for loop in PL/SQL. It looks like this:

```
BEGIN
FOR i in 1..99 LOOP
SELECT count(value || i) as v_number || i
FROM itemlist
WHERE v_number || i > 35
END LOOP
```

Apparently it doesn't work, the problem is I don't know how to concatenate value with index 1-99.

Comment: This is a problem that you have when you have denormalized data.  If you had one row per item, year, and value, then the query would be simple.

Comment: @eli, did any of the answers help you out? Could you comment or accept one?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`UNPIVOT` syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#unpivot)
to create a view. This is a one-time effort. Then the queries will be easier when performed on that view.

So first create the view (extend for all value columns):

```
CREATE VIEW v_itemlist AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM    unpivot_test
    UNPIVOT (value FOR value_id IN (
                value1 AS 1,
                value2 AS 2,
                value3 AS 3,
                ...
                value98 AS 98,
                value99 AS 99
            ));
```

Then you can do queries like:

```
SELECT   item, year,
         SUM(CASE value > 35 THEN 1 END) AS above_35,
         SUM(CASE value < 35 THEN 1 END) AS below_35,
FROM     v_itemlist
GROUP BY item, year;
```

Once you get used to using the view, you could consider to create your base table in that [normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) way, so you can potentially benefit from indexes and have the ease to insert and delete values separately, sort them, detect duplicates, etc. That is how relational databases are intended to be modelled and give the best value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN Value1 > 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v1_number,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Value2 > 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v2_number,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Value3 > 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v3_number,
       -- ...
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Value99 > 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v99_number
FROM   itemlist;
```

Then you can do copy/paste and find/replace change `>` to `<` to get the below values.

Or you can use PL/SQL to generate the query dynamically:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  qry  CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
  line_above VARCHAR2(4000);
  line_below VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 99 LOOP
    line_above := ', COUNT( CASE WHEN Value' || i || ' > 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v' || i || '_above_number';
    line_below := ', COUNT( CASE WHEN Value' || i || ' < 35 THEN 1 END ) AS v' || i || '_below_number';
    qry := qry || line_above || line_below;
  END LOOP;
  qry := 'SELECT' || SUBSTR( qry, 2 ) || ' FROM itemlist';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( qry );
  OPEN :cur FOR qry;
END;
/

PRINT :cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

i upvoted trincot's answer, but maybe you're looking for something more like this

```
create or replace function eval(tab in varchar2, col in varchar2, cond in varchar2) return number as
    ret number; 
begin
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||tab||' where '||col||cond into ret;
    return ret;
end;
```

and

```
select table_name, column_name, 
eval(table_name, column_name, '>35'), eval(table_name, column_name, '<35') 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = upper('itemlist') and column_name like 'value%' /*and data_type = 'NUMBER'*/
```